# How to make LaTeX optimize floats/tables placement if order doesn't matter

Tags: tables, floats

I have a bunch of tables that their order in the document doesn't matter. How can I reduce empty space to a minimum and make it more visually appealing? All the tables are in a separate chapter with not text at all.

Comment: May i ask what the tables include? It is quite strange, that the order of tables is completely not relevant.

Comment: @Johannes_B We are presenting some dummy database data and there are a bunch of tables (imported from csv) and we don't really care about the order.

Comment: Haw many (approximately) tables  have you got?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX assumes the order of the tables is important to you, and strictly respects that.

Probably the easiest (but not sexiest) way to get what you want is to reorder them by hand. Unless this is a frequent, repetitive task, you risk [xkcd's automation](http://xkcd.com/1319).

Answer (score 0):

Allow all possible positions in table environments:

```
\begin{table}[htbp!]
```

Fix tolerant defaults about the amount of float per page. Some like:

```
\setcounter{topnumber}{4}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{4}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{8} 
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{6}    
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.9}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.9} 
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{0.9} 
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.7}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{0.7}   
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}   % allow minimal text with figures
```

And finally, reorder the floats manually (cut & paste).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to change anything in my document

Comment: @orestisf  Then you should edit your question to add a  minimal working example (MWE) and explain what improvements you expect with respect the actual results of that MWE.